# Append the last level in Multiindex Dataframe on same length

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B':['x', 'y'], 'C':[1, 2], 'D':[0, 0]})
df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).mean()
    

            D
A   B   C   
1   x   1   0.0
2   y   2   0.0
```

I want it to have the same index in C.

```
            D
A   B   C   
1   x   1   0.0
        2   NaN
2   y   1   NaN
        2   0.0
```

The goal is to obtain a plot with a y-axis: "D" and an x-axis: "C", where the lines of different combinations ("A" and "B") are not broken if the value for "C" does not exist. In the following plot, it happened to be the case that e.g. the lines are broken between 15-18. I want to have connected lines even if the values in between are missing.

[image]

Comment: You can also use: `df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C']).unstack('C').stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: @mozway - Dupe not match, please find new one.

Comment: @mozway - Partly match solution with `BENY` now, `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)` return different ouput.

Comment: @mozway -  see, `df1.unstack(1).stack(0, dropna=False)` not match ouput too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), add not exist value(s) in range by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).mean()

r = range(1, 5)
df2 = df1['D'].unstack().reindex(columns=r).stack(dropna=False).to_frame(name='D')
print (df2)
         D
A B C     
1 x 1  0.0
    2  NaN
    3  NaN
    4  NaN
2 y 1  NaN
    2  0.0
    3  NaN
    4  NaN
```

EDIT: Missing values are not plotting, if possible replace them by some value, here `0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 2,2], 'B':['x', 'y','y','y'], 'C':[1, 2,3,2], 'D':[1,7,4,8]})
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).mean()
print (df1)
         D
A B C     
1 x 1  1.0
2 y 2  7.5
    3  4.0
    
#if unique triples A, B, C
#df1 = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])

r = range(1, 5)

df2 = (df1['D'].unstack(fill_value=0)
               .reindex(columns=r, fill_value=0)
               .stack(dropna=False)
               .to_frame(name='D'))
print (df2)
         D
A B C     
1 x 1  1.0
    2  0.0
    3  0.0
    4  0.0
2 y 1  0.0
    2  7.5
    3  4.0
    4  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks. When I plot my dataframe, the lines are broken as for example in level "C", the values between 15-18 are missing. How can I jump over these missing values such that the line is still connected. My problem plot is here, https://ibb.co/HK5QjY5

Comment: @nuemlouno - Can you edit question with your problem? It means not exist values in last level and is necessary add it?

Comment: I edit my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: @nuemlouno - Can you check edited answer?

Comment: Instead of jumping over the missing values, the plot is now looking like this https://ibb.co/myGGYm4, that is misleading since I don't know the value for missing values

Comment: @nuemlouno - it is problem, you need plot missing values? Need replace them, e.g. by `0`, answer was edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250106/discussion-between-nuemlouno-and-jezrael).